# redirecting output at cursor position in java

Tags: java

How can a text be sent to cursor position by clicking a button in java? Actually I am working on a project "On screen Keyboard" developing using java. I want to redirect the text with the click on button to cursor position like a normal keyboard key press event do.

Comment: What UI framework are you using? (this isn't a question about Java _per se_). Also, you probably want to ask this on StackOverflow instead of here.

Answer (score 1):

Hello You can try to use the Robot class [Robot doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html). 
It is used for example to automated test of UI.
For example a small Robot class:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;


public class SmallRobot { 

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Robot rob = null;
        try {
            rob = new Robot();
        }
        catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        rob.delay(10000);
        rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H);
        rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
        rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
        rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
    }
}
```

You can run this small app, ant then click on any text field on screen (for example Notepad window).
It will write in field/Notpad text "hello".
It emulates key press events on Keyboard.